# Css calling class into other style

Tags: css

I don't understand why this doesn't work

```
.mix{
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px / 5px 5px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #888;
} 
#adm_content_login, .mix{
  top:100px;
  position:relative;
  width:450px;
  height:200px;
  margin:auto;
  background-color:#ccc;
  text-align:center;
  border:5px solid #111;
}
```

When I try to call a class into another class with `adm_content_login, .mix` , because there is no need if I use this code each time I have the same content I have in the `.mix`. I don't understand what's wrong with this code. The CSS works if I put it into `adm_content_login`, but if I try using this method it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show us an example of it not working like you expect?

Comment: If you have trouble with English, please write your question in your native language and use [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/) to translate into English. It is recommended you post your question in both your native language and in the translated English.

Comment: The solo .mix class styles should be applying as well. It may help to create a jsfiddle to demonstrate.

Comment: The example no works , the result must show round corners into div adm_content_lobin without apply the class , i want call one class over style but i don´t know if it´s right put this #adm_content_login, . mix , thank´s

Comment: Need to see HTML. It's possible `#adm_content_login.mix` (no comma and space separator) may work

Comment: Your CSS is assigning the styles to any element with **id** `adm_content_login` and not to the class name. If you want to use it on the classname then you will have to change the css style to be `.adm_content_login` instead of `#adm_content_login`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you are trying to use .mix class with #adm_content_login you can make both of them either a class or id. for instance, if both of them are class you can you it like this

```
<div class="adm_content_login mix"></div>
```

notice that there is a space between two classes.

If that's not what you are trying to achieve then you can achieve something like that using LESS(CSS FRAMEWORK)

Comment: You are not trying to call a class into another class you are basically calling a class in an id. (# this is id symbol and (.) is class symbol)

Comment: yes ok , i want ad the class into the style for that div how i can put or apply this style into the css file and into this style for that div , regards

Answer (score 0):

you are **using** `class` but you **define** `id`

used to **this way** as **like this**

```
<div id="adm_content_login" class="mix"></div>
```